# COPY Failed: no source files were specified

Tags: docker, google-cloud-build

I am crafting a dockerfile to do couple of things. Listing the step below which throws the error when building the file.

I am downloading a tar.gz file and then extracting it to a location followed by downloading another .zip file and extracting that to a secondary location on the same parent directrory.

```
WORKDIR /opt/MicroFocus
RUN curl -O http://apache.mirror.amaze.com.au/nifi/1.9.2/nifi-1.9.2-bin.tar.gz
RUN tar xzvf nifi-1.9.2-bin.tar.gz
RUN curl -O https://storage.googleapis.com/xxxx/xxxxxx/NiFiIngest_12.2.0_LINUX_X86_64.zip 
RUN unzip NiFiIngest_12.2.0_LINUX_X86_64.zip
WORKDIR /opt/MicroFocus/NiFiIngest_12.2.0_Linux_X86_X64
COPY /opt/MicroFocus/NiFiIngest_12.2.0_Linux_X86_X64/idol-nifi-framework-12.2.0.nar /op/MicroFocus/nifi-1.9.2-bin/nifi-1.9.2/lib
```

However, when I try to build the docker file I get the following errors

```
Step 36/47 : WORKDIR /opt/MicroFocus/NiFiIngest_12.2.0_Linux_X86_X64
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e6e0e64c5490
Step 37/47 : COPY /opt/MicroFocus/NiFiIngest_12.2.0_Linux_X86_X64/idol-nifi-framework-12.2.0.nar /op/MicroFocus/nifi-1.9.2-bin/nifi-1.9.2/lib
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder486894156/opt/MicroFocus/NiFiIngest_12.2.0_Linux_X86_X64/idol-nifi-framework-12.2.0.nar: no such file o
r directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The COPY command is used to copy from the docker context inside the image. You have the file already inside the image so you need to use OS commands to copy files from one location to another.

Replace this:

```
COPY /opt/MicroFocus/NiFiIngest_12.2.0_Linux_X86_X64/idol-nifi-framework-12.2.0.nar /op/MicroFocus/nifi-1.9.2-bin/nifi-1.9.2/lib
```

with

```
RUN cp /opt/MicroFocus/NiFiIngest_12.2.0_Linux_X86_X64/idol-nifi-framework-12.2.0.nar /op/MicroFocus/nifi-1.9.2-bin/nifi-1.9.2/lib
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Didn't work. Step 37/47 : RUN cp /opt/MicroFocus/NiFiIngest_12.2.0_Linux_X86_X64/idol-nifi-framework-12.2.0.nar /op/MicroFocus/nifi-1.9.2-bin/nifi-1.9.2/lib
 ---> Running in 67cf79a721c7
cp: cannot stat '/opt/MicroFocus/NiFiIngest_12.2.0_Linux_X86_X64/idol-nifi-framework-12.2.0.nar': No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c cp /opt/MicroFocus/NiFiIngest_12.2.0_Linux_X86_X64/idol-nifi-framework-12.2.0.nar /op/MicroFocus/nifi-1.9.2-bin/nifi-1.9.2/lib' ret
urned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: Then your file has even a different name. try to add 'RUN ls -l /opt/MicroFocus/NiFiIngest_12.2.0_Linux_X86_X64/' and check the filename

Answer (score 0):

As you already set [WORKDIR](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir), you must not set path for your source COPY:

```
WORKDIR /opt/MicroFocus/NiFiIngest_12.2.0_Linux_X86_X64
COPY idol-nifi-framework-12.2.0.nar /op/MicroFocus/nifi-1.9.2-bin/nifi-1.9.2/lib
```